# Python - How to prepare vote results data for a cluster analysis - transforming and groupby

Tags: python, group-by, cluster-analysis, data-preprocessing, data-transform

I have imported a csv as a df in python. Below is an example of the data. I was wondering how I should prepare/transform this data. I would like to see which places vote the most similarly and was thinking of using a cluster analysis for this. Anyone have an idea how to prepare this data? Thank you

| Place | Vote | % yes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PLace A | Vote 1 | 54.2 |
| Place B | Vote 1 | 55.6 |
| Place C | Vote 1 | 46.8 |
| PLace A | Vote 2 | 34.6 |
| Place B | Vote 2 | 65.3 |
| Place C | Vote 2 | 35.7 |
| Place Z | Vote 208 | 48.7 |

I thought maybe that I should turn the values for vote into a column, so each vote would have a column. Then groupby the places so 1 row = 1 place. I haven't been able to use the groupby and then transform it into a new df.

Answer (score 0):

By your description seems you want to *pivot* the dataframe:

```py
print(df.pivot(index="Place", columns="Vote", values="% yes"))
```

Prints:

```
Vote     Vote 1  Vote 2  Vote 208
Place                            
PLace A    54.2    34.6       NaN
Place B    55.6    65.3       NaN
Place C    46.8    35.7       NaN
Place Z     NaN     NaN      48.7
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I tried this, I got the error "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"
Seems odd as there shouldn't be any rows that contain the same Place and Vote. I checked it there were duplicates with the code below but there weren't any. Have any idea what could be wrong?
yourdf1 = df1[df1[['Place','Vote']].nunique(axis=1) == 1]

Comment: @Raph Try to do `df = df.drop_duplicates(["Place", "Vote"])` before pivoting